# Optional map within list

Tags: terraform

For my aws batch job definition module, I need to create a resource_requirements block with vcpu, memory and gpu. The block needs to be a list of maps, in which the last gpu map should be skipped if `var.gpu = 0`

However I run into this error: `Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item` and can't seem to get past it(as I don't understand it).

```
locals {
  resource_requirements = [
    {
      "Type": "VCPU",
      "Value": tostring(var.vcpus)
    },
    {
      "Type": "MEMORY",
      "Value": tostring(var.memory)
    },
    dynamic "gpu_map" {
      for_each = var.gpu != 0 ? [1] : []
      content {
        Type  = "GPU",
        Value = tostring(var.gpu)
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My current solution thanks to @marko-e:

```
locals {
  cpu_map = [{
    "Type": "VCPU",
    "Value": tostring(var.vcpus)
  }]

  memory_map = [{
    "Type": "MEMORY",
    "Value": tostring(var.memory)
  }]

  gpu_map = var.gpu != "0" ? [{
      "Type": "GPU",
      "Value": tostring(var.gpu)
  }] : []

  resource_requirements = flatten([local.cpu_map, local.memory_map, local.gpu_map])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this, you could use the [`concat` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat) to concatenate three different local list variables into one:

```
locals {
  cpu = [
    {
      Type  = "VCPU"
      Value = tostring(var.vcpus)
    }
  ]

  memory = [
    {
      Type  = "MEMORY"
      Value = tostring(var.memory)
    }
  ]
  
  gpu_map = var.gpu != 0 : [{ Type = "GPU", Value = tostring(var.gpu)}] : []

  resource_requirements = flatten([local.cpu_map, local.memory_map, local.gpu_map])

}
```

There might be other ways of doing the same thing, but this should work. As a side note, `merge` might seem like a better solution, but they all have `"Type"` and `"Value"` keys, which would make it merge into one, probably the last map provided, i.e., you would probably end up with (when `var.gpu != 0`):

```
resource_requirements = [
  { 
     Type  = "GPU"
     Value = tostring(var.gpu)
  }
]
```

or with (when `var.gpu == 0`):

```
{
  Type  = "MEMORY"
  Value = "128"
}
```

Comment: Awesome!Just made a couple of changes, replaced `[{}]` with `[]` and concat with flatten - with concat I got this error: `Error: AWS Batch Job container_properties is invalid: decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field ContainerProperties.ResourceRequirements of type batch.ResourceRequirement`, I didn't understand this error actually. Added configuration to my answer as I couldn't edit your answer.

Thank you!